# Understanding lifetime of Rails model's class attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, lifecycle, class-attributes

Looking for the best way to do ownership validation in a Rails model without bloating my controllers. This means I need to pass the current_user to the model somehow.

I'm currently setting a class attribute on the User model to the current_user at the beginning of every request:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  cattr_accessor :current_user
end

class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
   before_filter :set_current_user
   def set_current_user
     User.current_user = current_user
   end
end
```

I'm not sure if I fully understand the lifetime of User.current_user in this scenario. Is it possible the value could change during the request?

I primarily want to know if the above is safe to use, and also if there is a better approach.

Comment: Depends in whether you run your app in multithreaded mode or not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer the first part of your question. The attribute will be saved in memory untill the User-class gets flushed/sent to garbage collector. That's usually when the VM or interpreter shuts down.

In an environment like Heroku, this variable can be stored between requests and an unauthenticated user will have access to the most recent user by accessing this variable, unless it's cleared out when the first user is done.

Comment: except that when a unauthenticated user visits, it will be set to nil

Comment: I'm having an entirely different problem that seems to be caused by this issue.  Can you provide any references that discuss the how variables are kept in memory between requests on Heroku?

Answer (score 1):

This is definitely the correct approach if you want to conform to best practices.  `current_user` is a controller method, and by following the [Chain-of-responsibility](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain-of-responsibility_pattern) pattern the `User` model should not know who the current user is.

Comment: It's interesting you say this because the OP *is* telling the User model to store who the current user is.

Comment: thanks... I'm more concerned about lifetime though... is it possible the value could change during the request?

Comment: It's just wrong. You're hiding a state to a place it shouldn't be. What if someone changes `current_user` during the request. Then the two vars will be out of sync.

Comment: @theodorton that's a valid point. Though still, I can think of no circumstance in which that would ever happen.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a safe approach:) Keep your state in the controllers, and business logic within the models.

If the current_user needs to be passed to the model layer, then the model shouldn't care about who this is. You could always use associations for filtering access to content.

`current_user.widgets.find(params[:id])`

Comment: I believe you've got it wrong. This isn't for actually storing any state; it is in fact for business logic. This allows me to to check ownership inside a model upon update. For instance in a Post model validation: self.user_id == User.current_user

Comment: That should go into the controller. They restrict access, not the model itself. You can do this by refactoring the update method on your controller to use find on a has_many-association.

Comment: I know this is a religious thing whether that is considered business logic or not, but I believe it is. I could make a method in Post such as: def is_owner?(user) and use that method in the controller, but that is tedious to do in every action.

Comment: @tybro0103 Your attributes have to be passed into the model one way or another too when you save, maybe then you should just move your entire model into the controller then? That 'ought to make things easier. (This is sarcasm, of course, to try and illustrate that justifying this defeats the entire purpose of MVC.)

Comment: Time.zone = current_user.time_zone is encouraged to be put in a before_filter in application_controller. Help me see the difference.

Comment: How do you handle the edit action? Redirect unless the model is valid? Authorization and authentication are Controller domain, not Model. The reason I wanna make that clear is if anyone else googles this, they'll know:)